# Dynamodb Cost vs Aurora Cost Comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

I want to store some personal data(eg: Name, Addresss and so on)  about the users but unaware of which database will be appropriate for my scenario.

I am planning to use either Aurora or Dynamodb? I think the cost will be the major factor. Which will be appropriate in terms of costs?

Comment: There lot other factors take part in deciding the data storage.... apart from what data you want to store, you also need to consider the size of data, the rate at which you store or retrieve the data, how consistent you want the data to be, how you want to query the data etc. If you have answers all these questions, you can check the pricing details of both Aurora and DynamoDb on AWS documentation and calculate the approximate cost by applying the values of above parameters. You can think of using MySQL RDS too instead of Aurora.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the DB (SQL, No-SQL, Graph etc) should be primarily driven by your workload and use case. Once you decide that, you can evaluate products in that category. If you are locked in to AWS, and you have to choose between the AWS database offerings, I would still recommend the same approach and then working backwards from there to optimize costs. Almost all db offerings in AWS have multiple configurations with price ranges varying from free to really expensive.

Let me know if you need more help!